# Devise and OmniAuth-Identity

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

Does anyone have experience backing Devise with OmniAuth-Identity?  I can't find any examples of it, and I'm not sure what params I need to set up where in order to make it happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that OmniAuth-Identity is a completely diferent way of email-password auth, so you don't need to use devise.
This railcast episode show how to configure OmniAuth-Identity
 http://railscasts.com/episodes/304-omniauth-identity